# Send props in a map function to another component in React with Typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I want to send props from a component to another through map. Done this before, but with typescript it causes problems.

First, I have defined the types/interface in a separate file which I import in both components:

```
 export interface ItemsProps {
 description?:string;

}

export interface Project {
Description: string;

}
```

I then have a container class that gets data from a provider (which works and have been tested). I then try to pass the data with map to a component (itemComponent).

```
import * as React from "react";
import {itemProps} from "./props";
import {itemComponent} from "./itemComponent";

export class itemContainer  extends React.Component<itemProps, itemState> {
private provider: ProjectItemProvider;

constructor(props: ItemsProps, context: itemsState) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {
    listItems: []
  };

private mapResultToProject(result: any[], type: ProjectType): Project {
    let ProjectLeader: string = result[this.props.projectLeaderSearchFieldString];
    if(ProjectLeader) {
      ProjectLeader = ProjectLeader.split('|')[1].trim();
    }

  private getProjectItems()  {
    this.provider.GetSiteItemsByContentId(this.props.publicContentTypeId, this.props.projectSearchFieldStrings).then((items: Project[]) => {
      const i: Project[] = [];
      items.map((result: any) => {
        i.push(this.mapResultToProject(result, ProjectType.Public));
      });
      this.setState({
        listItems: this.state.listItems.concat(i)
      });
    });
  }

public render(): JSX.Element {

          return (
            <div>

             {this.state.listItems.map((item: Project) => {

         <itemComponent

          description =  {item.Description}

          /> })}

            </div>
          )  }}
export default itemContainer;
```

In the component I define with props where the data should be shown:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {itemProps} from "./props";
import {itemComponent} from "./itemComponent";

export class itemComponent extends React.Component<itemProps, itemState> {

  constructor(props: itemsProps, context: itemsState) {
    super(props, context);

  }

public render():JSX.Element {

    return (

      <div>
        <p>{this.props.description}</p>
      </div>
);}}
```

However nothing is shown and the component does not get the data I send from the map as props to that component.

Comment: Why do you have two `itemContainer` components? Also can you show your code for `this.mapResultToProject`?

Comment: Miss type, should be "itemComponent" (use dummy names). Added mapResultToProject in my post: 
`private mapResultToProject(result: any[], type: ProjectType): Project {
    let ProjectLeader: string = result[this.props.projectLeaderSearchFieldString];
    if(ProjectLeader) {
      ProjectLeader = ProjectLeader.split('|')[1].trim();
    }